# In java what is the benefit of extending from an interface

Tags: java, oop

for example:

```
SortedSet EXTENDS Set
NavigableSet EXTENDS SortedSet
```

is the benefit finally gained at the bottom most level (one that actually implements)?. 
In above case it would be `TreeSet`

Would it be fair to say that if some class is EXTENDING an interface then that class SHOULD/MUST be an interface?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, only interfaces can extend other interfaces. Classes implement interfaces, they don't extend them.

The purpose of an interface which extends another interface is to show that `SortedSet` is an extension of the `Set` interface. `SortedSet` is a `Set`, with additional operations.

Comment: And as such, you can do something like `Set someSet = new TreeSet();` ignoring that it's a `SortedSet` in the process.

Answer (score 2):

> is the benefit finally gained at the bottom most level (one that actually implements)?

The benefit is the same as for interfaces in general: specifying a contract. Interface hierarchies basically just save you some typing and prevent unintentional mismatches: SortedSet doesn't have to repeat the methods in Set, and there is no risk to end up with the same functionality in slightly different methods.

> Would it be fair to say that if some class is EXTENDING an interface then that class SHOULD/MUST be an interface?

MUST would be correct. Classes cannot extend interfaces, only implement them.